# Postgres lookup tables over clustered data

Tags: database, postgresql

### Background

This is a simplified version of the **postgres** database I am managing:

```
TableA: id,name
TableB: id,id_a,prop1,prop2
```

This database has a peculiarity: when I select data, I only consider rows of `TableB` that have the same `id_a`. So I am never interested in selecting data from TableB with mixed values of `id_a`. Therefore, queries are always of this kind:

```
SELECT something FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.id=id_a
```

Some time ago, the number of rows in `TableA` grew up to `20000` rows and `TableB` up to `10^7` rows.

To first speedup queries I added a binary tree lookup table to the `TableB` properties. Something like the following:

```
 "my_index" btree (prop1)
```

### The problem

Now I have to insert new data, and the database size will became *more* than the double of its current size. Inserting data to `TableB` became too slow.

I understood that the slowness cames from the updating of `my_index.`
When I add a new row of `TableB,` the database have to reorder the `my_index`  lookup table.

I feel like this would be speeded up, if `my_index` was not over *all* elements.

**But I do not need** the new row, with a given `id_a` property to be sorted with a row having a different `id_a` property

### The question

How can I create an index on a table, where the elements are ordered *only* when they have a same common property (es. a column called `id_a`)?

Comment: Are you looking for a partial index? e.g. `create index on tableb (prop1) where id_a = 42`? Btw: an index is not "re-ordered" when you insert data into it. Inserting into a B-Tree index is quite efficient.

Comment: Why index prop1.. seems like you should be indexing id_a

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The question that I would immediately ask you if you want such an index is: Yes, but for *what* values of `id_a` do you want the index? And your answer would be “for all of them”.

If you actually would want an index only for *some* values, you could use a [*partial index*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX partidx ON tableb(prop1) WHERE id_a = 42;
```

But really you want an index for the whole table.

Besides, the `INSERT` would be just as slow unless the row inserted does not satisfy the `WHERE` condition of your index.

There are three things you can do to speed up `INSERT`:

1. Run as many `INSERT` statements as possible in a single transaction, ideally all of them.

   Then you don't have to pay the price of [`COMMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commit.html) after every single `INSERT`, and `COMMIT`s are quite expensive: they [require data to be written to the disk hardware](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-intro.html) (*not* the cache), and this is incredibly slow (1 ms a decent time).

   You can speed this up even more if you use [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html). That way the `INSERT` doesn't have to be parsed and prepared every time.
2. Use the SQL command [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) to insert many rows. `COPY` is specifically designed for bulk data import and will be faster than `INSERT`.
3. If `COPY` is to slow, usually because you need to `INSERT` a lot of data, the fatsest way is to drop all indexes, insert the data with `COPY` and then recreate the indexes. It can speed up the process by an order of magnitude, but of course the database is not fully available while the indexes are dropped.